# ReferenceError: Worker is not defined in fresh Nextjs project

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, web-worker

I'm investigating a larger issue where I am trying to import a webpacked javascript file into a NextJS project that uses `Worker` and keep getting `ReferenceError: Worker is not defined`. I've minimized it to the following:

- Create a fresh NextJS project with `npx create-next-app@latest`
- Inside that project, create a javascript file containing just the following line: `module.exports = Worker;`
- Go to `pages/_app.js` and try to import the file we just created in the previous step `const shouldThrow = require('../myFile.js')`.
- Run `npm run build`, should now throw `ReferenceError: Worker is not defined`

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: are you sure `Worker` is available in global scope

Comment: I'm quite new to Nextjs, but according to this I thougt it should be https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10899

Answer (score 0):

If you check [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#class-worker)

```
const { Worker } = require("node:worker_threads");

console.log("W", Worker);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this unfortunately does not solve my problem, as the question I supplied is a simplified version of me having a webpacked bundle that includes the line `module.exports = Worker;` which is causing problems. I want a way with which I can import the external file.